# Can we use angularJS within Jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jstree

I am using JStree and it uses Jquery. I have a bootstrap modal to be shown on performing some action in JStree like check/uncheck on a node. I have the modal hidden using `ng-show="showonclickinJStree"` `id="showonclickinJStree"`.

If I set `$scope.showonclickinJStree = true` within the jquery function, it doesn't work. The modal is not displayed. 
Only if I use `$('#showonclickinJStree').modal('show');` the modal shows up.

May I know why? Is it not allowed to use AngularJS definitions within Jquery functions?

I know it is not advisable to use 2 different approaches. But just to know how it supports.

Comment: Reverse is possible, if you declared your angular module, then you can use jquery within directives, services and controllers etc

Comment: You can rather use this Library https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, It's not good. You can use jquery inside angularjs. Angularjs is a framework(Module based development), Jquery is a library. Angular have some enough jquery functionality(JQLite).

Just see some basic difference
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-differences-between-jQuery-and-AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

You can put this line of code inside of your elements directive's `link` function:

```
app.directive('thedirective', function(){
   return {
      restrict:'EA',
      link:function(scope, el, attrs){
        $('#showonclickinJStree').modal('show'); 
      }
   };
});
```

Because directive's link function is the place where you can actually do some DOM manipulation work and it is mostly used in a standard way.

---

Your question:

#### *May I know why?*

Because with this `$scope.showonclickinJStree = true` modal can't be triggered. This same can be achieved in directives as suggested in the answer you can change it as:

```
link:function(scope, el, attrs){
    scope.showonclickinJStree = true;
}
```

Now as in the docs stated that any change outside or angular realm does not get reflected automatically. You need to tell angular to run the digest cycle to see if there are any change with `$digest()/$apply()` method. Not adviceable as this has to be done explicitly.